# Creating a login form that use tables in Access 2007

Tags: forms, authentication, ms-access-2007

I have created a login from, in it I have placed a "Username" field
I have managed to find a code that compares the value entered into this field (Username)
and as a result displayed a message

What I can not do is connect the value entered in the "username" filed to an existing table

Explanation:
I have a table of users and permissions (each user has permission)
For example:
Record 1: Username = 1 , permission = normal
Record 2: Username = 2 , permission= Special

I want to write code or macro that will take the value entered into the "username" field
and compare it to this table and then it will displayed an appropriate message

For example:
If the user write 1 the message will be: "Welcome regular user"
If the user write 2 the message will be: "Hey there special user"

What matters is that on the code I do not want to filter by 1 or 2 but by permission

This is the code that I have used in the first part:

```
Private Sub B15_Click()    
    Username.SetFocus      
    If Username = "1" Then    
        MsgBox "Welcome regular user"    
        DoCmd.Close    
    Else    
        If Username = "2" Then
            MsgBox "Hey there special user"    
        End If    
    End If    
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you think you're accomplishing with fake security? Why not use real security? Or some form of real user access control?

Comment: if there's no password entry, you could bind a combo box to your table and let them 'log in' that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DLookUp, but you should understand that none of this offers any form of security.

```
Private Sub B15_Click()
     Dim sPermission As String

     ''Not needed: Username.SetFocus

     ''If username is text, you will need quotes: "Username='" & Username & "'"
     sPermission = DLookUp("Permission", "UserTable", "Username=" & Username)

     ''You should first check that something is returned in sPermission

     MsgBox "Welcome " & sPermission & " user"

     DoCmd.Close

End Sub
```